# Checkmail validation for Contact Form 7 css is not coming

Tags: wordpress

Helo frineds

i used this plugin **Checkmail validation for Contact Form 7**

i got this output:- [image]

input type text is not coming

:(

See this is my contact form html

```
<p>Your Email Address <span class="required1">* </span> 
 [email* email id:postemail class:postemail]  </p>
<p> Confirm Email Address111<span class="required1">* </span>

[checkmail checkmail-477 "email"]
```

Comment: is it activated form the plugin section? or might be you missed some setting.

Comment: ya i activated it @jogesh_pi

Comment: I don't see a "checkmail" option on contact form 7?